# Прошу помочь исправить мой код. Раскладываю число на простые множители

Tags: python, алгоритм

Прошу помочь исправить мой код.
Раскладываю число на множители, но закралась ошибка:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
n=int(input("Integer: ")) 
factors = []
d = 2
while d * d <= n:
        if n % d == 0:
            factors.append(d)
            n//=d
        else:
            d += 1
        if n > 1:
            factors.append(n)
        else:
            break
print('{} = {}' .format(n,factors))
```

На выходе получется: 7 = [63, 3, 21, 3, 7]
А должно: 63 = 3 * 3 * 7
Прошу помочь исправить!